# Сброс пароля в django

Tags: python, django, password

сброс пароля в django.

```
               urls
   '''
       path('password_reset/', views.UserForgotPasswordView.as_view(), 
            name='password_reset'),
       path('password_reset_done/', views.UserPasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), 
            name='password_reset_done'),
       path('set-new-password/<uidb64>/<token>/', 
            views.UserPasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(),name='password_reset_confirm'),
       path('password_reset_complete/', views.UserPasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), 
            name='password_reset_complete')
    '''

        view

    '''
        class UserForgotPasswordView(PasswordResetView):

           template_name = 'scanner/password_reset_email.html'
           email_template_name = 'scanner/email/password_reset_mail.html'
           success_url = reverse_lazy('password_reset_done')


        class UserPasswordResetDoneView(PasswordResetDoneView):
           template_name = 'scanner/password_reset_done.html'


        class UserPasswordResetConfirmView(PasswordResetConfirmView):
           template_name = 'scanner/password_reset_confirm.html'
           success_url = reverse_lazy('password_reset_complete')


        class UserPasswordResetCompleteView(PasswordResetCompleteView):
            template_name = 'scanner/password_reset_complete.html'

    '''

        html(password_reset_confirm)

    '''
        <form method="post>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
          {{ form.password1.errors }}
             <label for="password" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
             <div class="cols-sm-10">
                 <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock fa-lg" aria- 
                      hidden="true"></i></span>
                        {{form.password1}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

          <div class="form-group">
          {{ form.password2.errors }}
           <label for="confirm" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock fa-lg" 
                          aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        {{form.password2}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
           <button type="submit" class="glow-on-hover">Подтвердить</button>
       </form>
    '''
```

Все проходит штатно) письмо приходит на почту, при переходе по ссылке в письме переходит на сайт с формой для изменения пароля. Но если нажать на кнопку "Подтвердить" ничего не происходит хотя в Pycharm видно что POST запрос уходит.

[image: Форма для изменения пароля]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]